# iOS SDK. Show In-Call status bar

Tags: ios, sdk, in-call

Any one know how to show In-Call Status Bar with message from application when it is going to be in background? I know many applications from AppStore which can perform it. For instance: http://myevoz.com/. As I understood, they use SBStatusBar class to show it. I've tried to call setDoubleHeightStatusString method and got no result.

Any ideas or links to examples?

Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/

Answer (score 2):

So, now I can see red double-height status bar without any SpringBoard tricks and using the only legal APIs. You just need to add background mode support for sound and perform recording simulation. That's all. You will see your application name on red statusbar, see the answer here:

[SBStatusBarController instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/)