# What is the accepted means whereby an app can display the double-height status bar, viz. the 'in-call' status bar

Tags: ios, background

This is not a question about how to modify a view when the double status bar is shown.
Nor is it a question about how to [mimic a double-height status bar within an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319382/ios-pulsing-red-double-height-status-bar).

It is how to display, while an app is backgrounded, a double-height status bar. Namely, what are the preconditions and mechanisms for an app that wants to be accepted by the app store to use this functionality? Third party apps do, mostly telephony and navigation apps. Google Maps goes so far as to display turn-by-turn directions *over the home view*.

Now, one can do this outside legal APIs by getting the SBStatusBar class and sending it appropriate messages. The class' interface is [available online](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBStatusBarController). But I want to do it legitimately.

Here is [one post asking the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191196/ios-sdk-show-in-call-status-bar). The only answer is how to fake background recording, which brings up a 'recording' bar that is not controllable by the application.

Here is what I think so far: Background modes 'audio' and 'navigation' are allowed to do this. (EG, this question showing how to [fake background audio recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/)). Again, I want to do it legitimately - so responses from developers who have done this with shipping app-store apps are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How exciting; my first 'tumbleweed' badge.

Comment: Looking for the same thing. You got any leads ?

Comment: @Deepukjayan I believe this to be impossible in current versions of the OS on a non-jailbroken device. For reasons.